# JPA/Hibernate @SecondaryTable @PrimaryKeyJoinCloumn reference a non-primary column in the primary table

Tags: hibernate, join

I have two tables primary_table and secondary_table.

The hibernate entity is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "primary_table")
@SecondaryTable(name = "secondary_table", pkJoinColumns =
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="secondary_id", referencedColumnName="secondary_id"))
public class Primary{
    ...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "primary_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long primaryId;

    ... columns in the primary table
    ... columns in the secondary table
}
```

The tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE primary_table
(
    primary_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    secondary_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( primary_id)
)
CREATE TABLE secondary_table
(
    secondary_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY( secondary_id)
)
```

In short: the primary column of the secondary column referenced a non-primary column of the primary table.

However, when starting the app, hibernate complains:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: secondary_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(primary_table) and its related supertables and secondary tables
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:828) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
```

I've changed the referencedColumnName to the primary_id of the primary table, in effect is let the primarykey references the primarykey, and hibernate is satisfied. However, I am working with a legacy database and can not change the schema.

What is wrong with my code?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Primary column of the secondary table referenced a non-primary column of the primary table, and this is the problem. De-facto, you have ManyToOne relationship between primary and secondary table, and it should be treated and mapped as ManyToOne regardless of semantics of this tables.